# CKEditor - overriding a core plugin

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, fckeditor

How do I override a core CKEditor (v3) plugin with my own implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options:

1. Replace the core plugin's folder in `_source/plugins`.
2. Name your plugin something different, load it with `config.extraPlugins`, and prevent the core plugin from loading with `config.removePlugins`